# How to use HttpUrlConnection POST in java for login

Tags: java, android, post, authentication

I need to use `POST` method to login and get authorization token.I have to send headers and request body. Tried adapting HttpUrlConnection examples for myself. What am I missing?

```
        URL url;
        String response = "";
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap();
        map.put("grant_type", "password");
        map.put("scope", "openid");
        map.put("username", username);
        map.put("password", password);
        try {
            url = new URL(your_url);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic <...>=");

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(map));
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                String line;
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += line;
                }
            } else {
                response = "";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
```

---

```
    private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Have you searched for this? There are a lot of examples to send post data via java to http. Here is one similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily

Comment: What happens when you run your code? What actual problem are you having?

Comment: @Kenster i am not getting any response.

Comment: @Kenster am i sending body of the request right?